# Flash Detection on Safari mac using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, flash, safari

Flash detection is currently broken for Safari 8  I am using the following code

```
/**
 * check if flash is installed and enabled on the browser
 */
function isFlashInstalled(){
    var hasFlash = false;
    try {
      var fo = new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash');
      if (fo) {
        hasFlash = true;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (navigator.mimeTypes
            && navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash'] != undefined
            && navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash'].enabledPlugin) {
        hasFlash = true;
      }
    }
    return hasFlash;
}
```

but it always return true on safari even when the flash is blocked and disabled from settings..

So I need to know how to detect if flash is blocked or disabled on Safari browser

Comment: Have you tried [swfobject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) ?

Comment: yes .. its always see that flash is enabled and get all flash details even its blocked !!!

Answer (score 0):

Check `document.plugins` instead of `navigator` or `window` feature detection:

```
document.plugins
```

> When expecting the instantiated plug-in, use document["myPlugin"] instead of window["myPlugin"]. document["myPlugin"] will not match fallback elements when the parent is instantiated.

Or use a check for the `<param>` element:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("param").length;
```

```js
function paramCheck(e)
  {
  console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("param").length);
  window.removeEventListener("scroll", paramCheck, false);
  } 
   
window.addEventListener("scroll", paramCheck, false);
```

```css
body { height:  1200px;}
```

**References**

- [Apply tag attributes in Adobe Flash Professional](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html)
- [Object element fallback applies to the DOM (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622942)
- [EventTarget.removeEventListener() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)